# Recyclerview Onclick passing specific data when click cardview into activity

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, onclick, android-recyclerview

What I'm trying to do is to pass a data from a specific user into another activity **using it's userID as unique ID**
It keeps send the same data into the other activity, I dont know how to do it

[image: this is the UI of fragment_home]

This is code is for the **Fragment_Home** where I use to get data from `Firebase` and populate it into the `RecyclerView`, and where the `Onclick` is in at the moment.

```
public class FragmentRO_Home extends Fragment {

private Intent intent;
private DatabaseReference database;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Recycler_View_Adapter adapter;
TextView TV_nodata;
private String uid;
private String nombre;
public FragmentRO_Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor    qwe
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_ro__home,container,false);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final List<Data> data = new ArrayList();

    TV_nodata = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TV_result);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    adapter = new Recycler_View_Adapter(data, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    fill_with_data();
```

This is the onclick which I'm using with recyclerview and it's functionable.

```
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new CustomRVItemTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new RecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            if (position == 0){
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReportInformation.class);
                intent.putExtra("idData",uid);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if (position == 1){
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReportInformation.class);
                intent.putExtra("idData",uid);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if (position == 2){
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReportInformation.class);
                intent.putExtra("idData",uid);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if (position == 3){
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReportInformation.class);
                intent.putExtra("idData",uid);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if (position == 5){
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReportInformation.class);
                intent.putExtra("idData",uid);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
    return view;
}
```

**This is the method to where I populated my recyclerview from getting data's in the firebase.**

```
public void fill_with_data() {
    database.child("data_home").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot d) {

            if (d.exists()) {
                List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot dataw : d.getChildren()) {
                    Data data = dataw.getValue(Data.class);
                    list.add(data);

                    uid = (data.usirayd);
                    nombre = (data.title);
                }
                for (Data data : list) {
                    adapter.insert(new Data(data.title, data.description, data.condition, data.time,data.usirayd));
                }
            }else {
                TV_nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: what is your query and what is the problem that you are encountering?

Comment: What is the issue? you haven't posted what issue you are facing.

Comment: what issue you are facing and one more thing When you are using position onclick event and if passing the same data then don`t use condition on position simply send data from position. remove if else of position u are sending same data for each position.

Comment: Whenever I click on the viewholder the data it's getting is only from the firebase 1st node

Comment: That's what I'm having a problem at @UsmanKurd

Comment: It keeps send the same data into the other activity, I dont know how to do it. @UsmanKurd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new CustomRVItemTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new RecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {

            if(data.size()>position){
              if (data.get(position)!= null){
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReportInformation.class);
                intent.putExtra("idData",data.get(position).usirayd);
                startActivity(intent);
               }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list is of Data type so what you need to do is make Data class parcleable and then get object form the clicked position and send it to activity.
Sample code is something like this

```
 public void onClick(View view, int position) {
Data dataObject = list.get(position);
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReportInformation.class);
                intent.putExtra("idData",uid);
intent.putExtra("Data",dataObject);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
```

If you want to send single id of clicked position then  just get Id from list object and send like this

```
 uid= list.get(postion).getUserId;
```

and send it in intent

and in other class/activity receice that parcelable object like this

```
Data dataObjectReceived = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Data");
```

and if you want to get single entity then get it by its key

Answer (score 1):

When clicking on the `cardView` you want to pass the data into your activity or fragment for that you need to make one interface for example in my case may use one `FriendModel`

**Interface**

```
public interface OnFriendListClickListener {
    void onItemClick(FriendModel model, int position);
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class FriendListActivity extends AppCompactActivity
        implements
        OnFriendListClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend);

        //...
        rvRemoveFriendList.setAdapter(new FriendListAdapter(context, list, this));

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(FriendModel model, int position) {
    //your code here
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class FriendListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendListAdapter.FriendListHolder> {

    private List<FriendModel> friendList;
    private Context context;
    private OnFriendListClickListener listener;

    public FriendListAdapter(Context context,
                             List<FriendModel> friendList,
                             OnFriendListClickListener listener,) {
        this.context = context;
        this.friendList = friendList;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public FriendListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new FriendListHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_friend, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FriendListHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvFriendNumber.setText(friendList.get(position).getFriendMobile());

        holder.llFriendListItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onItemClick(friendList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()),
                        holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

    }

  //......     

}
```